# In my simple game, the player always erases the laser warnings, and I cannot seem to fix it.

Tags: javascript

I made a simple game. The goal is to stay alive by avoiding the lasers. However, every time the player moves across the laser warning, it erases the laser, making it look weird. I have already tried redrawing the warnings, but every time that happens it doesn't work and makes it buggier.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Drift 2
</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Drift 2</h1>
<h2>by Milesman34</h2>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<strong><p id="score">Score</p></strong>
</center>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    //MARK: Set up the canvas + canvas variables and draws the border + background
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    var blockSize = 20;
    var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
    var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    //MARK: Defines arrays and variables
    var shooterArray = [];
    var score = 0;
    //MARK: Defines functions
    function getRandomFromInterval(interval) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * interval);
    };
    //MARK: Defines game over function
    var gameEnd = 0;
    function gameOver () {
        setTimeout (function () {
            gameEnd = 1;
            clearInterval (scoreEffects);
            clearInterval (fireEffects);
            ctx.clearRect(blockSize, blockSize, width - (blockSize * 2), height - (blockSize * 2))
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
            ctx.fillRect(blockSize, blockSize, width - (blockSize * 2), height - (blockSize * 2));
            ctx.font = "60px Courier";
            ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
            ctx.fillText("Game Over", width / 2, height / 2);
        }, 149);
    };
    //MARK: Defines the player
    function Player (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
    //MARK: Defines the function that draws the player
    Player.prototype.draw = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(185, 185, 185)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    var player = new Player(width / 2, height / 2);
    player.draw();
    //MARK: Defines the functions that move the player
    Player.prototype.moveLeft = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
        this.x = this.x - 20;
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x + 20, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    Player.prototype.moveRight = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
        this.x = this.x + 20;
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x - 20, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    Player.prototype.moveUp = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
        this.y = this.y - 20;
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y + 20, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    Player.prototype.moveDown = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
        this.y = this.y + 20;
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y - 20, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    Player.prototype.checkWallCollision = function () {
        if (this.x === 0 || this.x === width - 20 || this.y === 0 || this.y === height - 20) {
            gameOver();
        };
    };
    //MARK: Defines the Shooter
    function Shooter (x, y, direction) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        if (["left", "right", "up", "down"].indexOf(direction) != -1) {
            this.direction = direction;
        };
        shooterArray.push(this);
    };
    //MARK: Defines the function that draws the Shooter
    Shooter.prototype.draw = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(185, 185, 185)";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    //MARK: Defines the function that fires the Shooter
    var timeoutID = null;
    function fireLeftRight(y) {
        if (gameEnd === 0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
            ctx.fillRect(blockSize, y, width - (blockSize * 2), blockSize);
            if (player.y === y) {
                gameOver();
            };
        };
    };
    function fireLeftRightWarn(y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
        for (i = 1;i < widthInBlocks - 1;i++) {
            ctx.fillRect(i * blockSize + (blockSize / 4), y + (blockSize / 4 * 1.5), blockSize / 2, blockSize / 4);
        };
        timeoutID2 = setTimeout (function () {
            clearTimeout (timeoutID);
            timeoutID = setTimeout (fireLeftRight(y), 100);
        }, 600);
    };
    function fireUpDown(x) {
        if (gameEnd === 0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
            ctx.fillRect(x, blockSize, blockSize, height - (blockSize * 2));
            if (player.x === x) {
                gameOver();
            };
        };
    };
    function fireUpDownWarn(x) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
        for (i = 1;i < heightInBlocks - 1;i++) {
            ctx.fillRect(x + (blockSize / 4 * 1.5), i * blockSize + (blockSize / 4), blockSize / 4, blockSize / 2);
        };
        timeoutID2 = setTimeout (function () {
        clearTimeout (timeoutID);
        timeoutID = setTimeout (fireUpDown(x))
        }, 600);
    };
    Shooter.prototype.fire = function () {
        if (this.direction === "left" || this.direction === "right") {
            timeoutID = setTimeout (fireLeftRightWarn(this.y), 1);
        } else {
            timeoutID = setTimeout (fireUpDownWarn(this.x), 1)
        };
    };
    //MARK: Creates the required shooters
    for (i = 1;i < heightInBlocks - 1;i++) {
        new Shooter(0, i * blockSize, "right");
    };
    for (i = 1;i < heightInBlocks - 1;i++) {
        new Shooter(width - blockSize, i * blockSize, "left");
    };
    for (i = 1;i < widthInBlocks - 1;i++) {
        new Shooter(i * blockSize, 0, "down");
    };
    for (i = 1;i < widthInBlocks - 1;i++) {
        new Shooter(i * blockSize, height - blockSize, "up")
    };
    for (i = 0;i < shooterArray.length;i++) {
        shooterArray[i].draw();
    };
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(185, 185, 185)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, blockSize);
    ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, blockSize);
    ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
    ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, height - blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
    //MARK: Draws the score
    function drawScore () {
        $("#score").text("Score: " + Math.floor(score));
    };
    //MARK: Convert keycodes to directions
    var directions = {
        37: "left",
        38: "up",
        39: "right",
        40: "down"
    };
    //MARK: This is the interval loop
    var scoreEffects = setInterval (function () {
        score += 0.1;
        drawScore();
        player.draw();
        player.checkWallCollision();
    }, 100);
    $("body").keyup(function (event) {
            if (gameEnd != 1) {
                var moveDir = directions[event.keyCode];
                if (moveDir === "left") {
                    player.moveLeft();
                } else if (moveDir === "right") {
                    player.moveRight();
                } else if (moveDir === "up") {
                    player.moveUp();
                } else if (moveDir === "down") {
                    player.moveDown();
                };
            };
        });
    var fireEffects = setInterval (function () {
        ctx.clearRect(blockSize, blockSize, width - (blockSize * 2), height - (blockSize * 2))
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(225, 225, 225)";
        ctx.fillRect(blockSize, blockSize, width - (blockSize * 2), height - (blockSize * 2));
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(185, 185, 185)";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, height - blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
        for (i = 0;i < shooterArray.length;i++) {
            if (getRandomFromInterval(30) === 0) {
                shooterArray[i].fire();
            };
        };
    }, 750);
</script>
```

Comment: It is unclear to me, having viewed this in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2keb9930/) what the intended functionality is.

Comment: Why not draw the player on a separate canvas layer. Have 2 canvases on top of each other. Put the player canvas on top and make it have a clear background. `fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";`
Then you don't need to worry about the player movements clearing the laser warning's drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working project here: https://jsfiddle.net/ay7kp7yb/1/

I think the best approach to solve this problem is to work with the classic pattern. That way all events that occur in the game need to be chained to a main loop (see: [Game Loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html)).

something like:

```
while (true)
{
  processInputs();
  updateObjects();
  render();
}
```

In your code some events happening independently with **setTimeout / setInterval**, it becomes very complex to "align" events.

I recommend you to use two combined techniques, the first is to centralize all events in a single loop (main game loop) and the second is to create a set of states to control the game.

Game states:

```
// game states
var STATE_TITLE_SCREEN = 0;
var STATE_GAME_STARTING = 1;
var STATE_RUNNING = 2;
var STATE_PLAYER_DYING = 3;
var STATE_GAME_OVER_SCREEN = 4;

// current state
var gameState = STATE_TITLE_SCREEN;

// time of the current state
var gameStateTime = 0;

// change the state and reset the time of last state
function setGameState(state) {
    gameState = state;
    gameStateTime = 0;
}
```

Main loop:

```
var minIteractionTime = 10;
var mainGameLoop = setInterval (function () {

    switch (gameState) {

        case STATE_TITLE_SCREEN:
            // Title screen (on press space bar, change gameState to STATE_GAME_STARTING)
        break;

        case STATE_GAME_STARTING:
            // Starting game, reset variables, countdown to start, etc...
            score = 0.0;

            // run the game after 5s
            if (gameStateTime>5000)
                setGameState(STATE_RUNNING);

        break;

        case STATE_RUNNING:
            score += (0.1/100.0);  // 0.1 points after 100 miliseconds

            // CLEAR THE SCREEN HERE

            drawScore();
            player.draw(); // draw the player ONLY here
            laserWarning.draw(); // Draws the warnings AFTER draw the player
            laserbeam.burn(player); // try to burn the player
        break;



        case STATE_PLAYER_DYING:
            // player dying animation..

            // after 5s, change show the game over screen
            if (gameStateTime>5000)
                setGameState(STATE_GAME_OVER_SCREEN);
        break;

        case STATE_GAME_OVER_SCREEN:
            // draw the game over screen here

            // after 5s returns to the title screen
            if (gameStateTime>5000)
                setGameState(STATE_TITLE_SCREEN);
        break;
    }

    // add the loop time in the gameStateTime variable
    gameStateTime += minIteractionTime;

}, minIteractionTime);
```

LaserWarning class:

```
LaserWarning.prototype.draw = function () {
    this.warningTime += minIteractionTime;

    if (this.warningTime>100) {
        // draw the warning only after firsts 100ms
    }

    if (this.warningTime>=750) { // warning time
        // timer reset
        this.warningTime = 0;
    }

}
```

LaserBeam class:

```
Laserbeam.prototype.burn = function (player) {
    this.warmingUpTime += minIteractionTime;

    if (this.warmingUpTime>=750) { // same time of warning

        // draw the laser

        // check if burns the player
        if (player.checkWallCollision()) {
            setGameState(STATE_PLAYER_DYING);
        }
    }
}
```

Input iteractions:

```
var gameKeys = {
    37: "left",
    38: "up",
    39: "right",
    40: "down",
    32: "space"
};

// for all iteractions, check the current state
$("body").keyup(function (event) {

    var lastKey = gameKeys[event.keyCode];

    switch (gameState) {
        case STATE_RUNNING:
            if (lastKey === "left") {
                player.moveLeft();
            } else if (lastKey === "right") {
                player.moveRight();
            } else if (lastKey === "up") {
                player.moveUp();
            } else if (lastKey === "down") {
                player.moveDown();
            };
        break;

        case STATE_TITLE_SCREEN:
            if (lastKey=="space")
                setGameState(STATE_GAME_STARTING);
        break;
    }
});
```

You should only adjust the positioning variables when moving the player and do not redraw it in the new position, this will happen in **player.draw ();**, in the STATE_RUNNING, before draw the warning.

If the user press the right arrow two times in less than 10ms (minIteractionTime) the player will be drawn only once! If you need to be more precise just reduce the value of minIteractionTime.

The variable **minIteractionTime** controls the framerate.

Comment: I tried doing this. However, it now freezes when it enters the GAME_RUNNING state. Code:

http://pastebin.com/tmCDA7jj

Comment: Hello @melesman34, i made some changes and now i believe it is working properly. I left it well commented so you understand the changes I made. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ay7kp7yb/1/)